# Autoprefixer hell - Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, sass, rake, autoprefixer

So, I'm trying to precompile my assets in Ruby on Rails, but every time I do it gives me:
`autoprefixer: /Desktop/Job/RailsApp/app/assets/stylesheets/application.scss:32473:3: Gradient has outdated direction syntax. New syntax is like`to left`instead of`right`.`

Now, I understand that the `linear-gradient`new syntax should be like it says, "to left" instead of "right". And if it's "top" then it should be "to bottom". I've gone through all of my css files and changed all of those lines of code to conform to the syntax.

But, I'm still getting that "error"? Which seems to be slowing down my page loading on my web-rails/app.

More or less, my question is if anyone knows how to fix this?
Also, is there any way for me to look at the application.scss and decifer the ":32473:3"? I've looked in that file and formatted the code for scss, but when I look at the 32,473rd line there isn't any "linear-gradient" there...

I have a mix of scss and css files, I don't know if that makes a difference when precompiling?

I'm using:
Rails 4.2.6
ruby 2.2.3p173

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems to have something to do with the 'config.assets.css_compressor = :sass' setting in the production.rb environment. As soon as I commented that out, it works without giving that error and speeds up the load times for all the pages.

Answer (score 11):

Despite autoprefixer saying "New syntax is like to left instead of right" it had to do with the top to bottom syntax for me.

ERROR:

```
 background: linear-gradient(top, #f5c304 50%,#d6a900 100%);
```

NO ERROR:

```
 background: linear-gradient(to bottom, #f5c304 50%,#d6a900 100%);
```

Comment: @Corey if that solved your issue would you mind marking the question as answered?

Answer (score 1):

My approach:

```
background: linear-gradient(0deg, red, yellow);
```

Comment: I'll try that out, I still get the syntax error. Even though it doesn't seem to affect anything, it would be good to get rid of the error. @sNICkerssss